# https redirection loop even with X-Forwarded-Proto

Tags: apache, https, centos, varnish

We are building a new server  with :
Pound -> Varnish -> Apache -> CentOS.

Since Varnish doesn't work in SSL we are setting "X-Forwarded-Proto" to "https" in Pound and we are detecting that way if we are in https.

It's working when we access directly a url like https://example.com but not when we do a redirection from "http" to "https" with "htaccess" or "PHP".   It's seem like the  X-Forwarded-Proto isn't forwarded with the redirection.  So we get stuck in an infinite redirection loop.

We have found a way to perform the redirection with javascript but we would prefer to have a server side solution.

So we wondering if there is a setting to change in apache, pound, varnish, etc. ?

We have tried a lot of solutions like:

```
////////////////
// htaccess
////////////////////
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
  RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com [L,R]


///////////////////
// php 
//////////////////
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https'){
    $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on'; 
}

if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'on'){
    header('Location: '. 'https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
}

Our pound config look like:

//////////////////
// pound
///////////////
ListenHTTPS

      Address 0.0.0.0 # all interfaces
      Port 443
      AddHeader "X-Forwarded-Proto: https"
      HeadRemove "X-Forwarded-Proto"
      HeadRemove "X-Forwarded-For"
      Cert "/path/to/certificate.pem

      Service
            BackEnd
                  Address 10.0.0.1
                  Port 80
                  Priority 1
            End

      End
End
```

We have passed a lot of time on that problem thanks to help us!

Comment: We’ve finally fix our problem.
We had to put “RewriteLocation 0 “In the “ListenHTTP” and to fix a domain name issu in the config.

Comment: Add your comment as your answer please

Comment: Thank you for this. I know this is old, but this should be marked as solved. What a frustrating problem.

Answer (score 3):

As noted above:

> We had to:
>
> - Put `RewriteLocation 0` in the `ListenHTTPs`
> - Fix a domain name issue in the config

```
ListenHTTPS

  ReWriteLocation 0
```

Comment: We ran into this exact issue, and this is _almost_ the solution. For us, the `ReWriteLocation 0` needed to go in `ListenHTTP` (_not_ HTTPS), since it was the non-SSL traffic causing the redirect loop.

Comment: This was literally driving me crazy and I spent hours today trying to figure out what portion of my configuration was off, if it was the browser cache, etc. My setup is Pound in front of Apache and I was getting the loop error. This one line was the answer. And same for me, it had to go in ListenHTTP.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, Varnish was configured to normalize URLs and removed scheme and domain:

```
set req.url = regsub(req.url, "^http[s]?://[^/]+", "");
```

So that the redirect response for http://example.com to https://example.com would be cached and the request to https://example.com would return this cached response.

Removing this normalization or adding

```
hash_data(req.http.Https);
```

to `sub vcl_hash` helped.